# Determining the power of the test in this question

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, self-study, normal-distribution

The following problem is from ***Devore's Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences, 8th edition***, exercise 8.1 question 33:

> Reconsider the accompanying sample data on expense ratio(%) for large-cap growth mutual funds first introduced in Exercise 1.53:
>
> [image]

I cannot figure out why I am getting a wrong answer for **part c** of the problem.

1) $H_0 = 1$ vs $H_a > 1$

2)The rejection region is: $t \ge 2.539$ for the test statistic $\dfrac{\bar x -1}{s/\sqrt{n}}$
where $n = 20, s = 0.4485$

here's my attempt for part c:

$\beta = \operatorname{P}(\text{$H_0$ is not rejected when it's false})\\$
$= \operatorname{P}\left(\bar{x} \ge\dfrac{ 2.539s}{\sqrt{n}} + 1 \text{  when $\bar x \sim N(1.33, 0.5)$}\right)\\ =  \operatorname{P}\left(\bar x \ge 1.2546 \text{  when $\bar x \sim N(1.33, 0.5)$}\right) \\= \operatorname{P}( z\ge -0.15)$

Therefore, power  = $ 1 - \beta = \phi(-0.15)  = 0.4404$

But the answer given is $0.66$. Can anyone help me figure out my mistake?